# How to get Controller context outside http request .e.g in background service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a task to send email which contain Html view once in a day.
I created a background service for it using hangfire.
The problem is that when i render view to string it requires controller context which is null in this case.

I have followed below tutorial which say you can create controller context
https://www.codemag.com/Article/1312081/Rendering-ASP.NET-MVC-Razor-Views-to-String

But the problem is that HttpContext.Current is null too in this case.
How can i use HttpContext in background jobs?

Comment: I would search for information on how to unit test your controller. In order to test the controller you have to solve the exact same problems - creating an instance and calling its method without any `HttpContext` or request.

Answer (score 0):

The application object is shared by all asp.net requests in the same application.  However, it can not be accessed from outside the application.  Also, a windows service doesn't have an HttpContext because it is not handled through asp.net.  That's why HttpContext.Current is null; there is no HttpContext for the service.

If you need to share data across application boundaries things get a little more tricky.  One of the simplest approaches would be to use a database or xml file to save and read the values.  That way both applications could access data from the same data store.

Comment: I need to render a view as string

Comment: why do you need? you can generate the email and save it in a nosql database. and have your background service access Nosql and send the email

Comment: again, The email i want to generate contain html view, which contain table how can i create html dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can create simple web service with your HTML pages and DB context and use MvcMailer:
[MvcMailer manual](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide)

Or create pdf from dynamically HTML using Rotativa:

```
var viewAsPdf = new ViewAsPdf("viewName", viewModel);
var file = viewAsPdf.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);
var path = Path.GetTempPath();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path + @"\myHtml.pdf", file);
```

if you have JS code in your page then add CustomSwitches to ViewAsPdf:

```
new ViewAsPdf("viewName", viewModel)
{
  CustomSwitches = "--no-stop-slow-scripts --javascript-delay 9000"
};
```

Or use RazorViewEngine for generate your string from HTML in controller and saving to storage. Something like this:
[create custom RazorViewEngine](https://wouterdekort.com/2012/10/12/rendering-an-asp-net-mvc-view-to-a-string-in-a-web-api-controller/)

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
var contextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(context); 
var routeData = new RouteData();     
routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);     
var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(contextBase,  
                                                  routeData,    
                                                  new EmptyController());
var razorViewEngine = new RazorViewEngine();
var razorViewResult = razorViewEngine.FindView(controllerContext,viewName,"",false);
var writer = new StringWriter();
var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext,razorViewResult.View,new ViewDataDictionary(viewData),new TempDataDictionary(),writer);
razorViewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);
return writer.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but problem remains there, HttpContext is null when i call it from background service